# error when using link_to to create a like

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

when i'm clicking on the link i'm getting this error:

```
 No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"likes",
 :doweet_id=>2}
```

this is the link_to code:

```
 link_to image_tag("/images/friends/thumbs-up.jpg"),  like_path(:doweet_id => doweet.id), :method => :post
```

in the routes:

```
  resources :likes
```

in likes controller:

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :html, :js

  def create 
    @like = Like.new(:doweet_id => params[:doweet_id])
    #push(comment)  
    flash[:notice] = "Like successfully created" if @like.save
    respond_with( @like, :layout => !request.xhr? )
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
link_to image_tag("/images/friends/thumbs-up.jpg"),  likes_path(:doweet_id => doweet.id), :method => :post, :remote => true
```

Comment: this is not the problem.. i'm using ajax to show the like... and i'm saying that i'm going to /likes/2 for example when i'm clicking on the like link

Comment: oh... so you need just add `:remote` option to your link! see my update

Comment: fl00r is right. The method post will probably be in the arguments. Though saying that you shouldn't be linking with the method :post. Post being a destructive action and all. But for a quick way to do it, that's the way.

Comment: oh. it should be `likes_path` I believe

Comment: The action 'index' could not be found for LikesController

Comment: this is taking me to /likes.2 for exmaple

Comment: i thogut it working beacuse the ajax thing it looks like its going to /likes?doweet_id=2 for example but when i click without the remote true its goes to /likes/2

Comment: `respond_with( @like, :layout => !request.xhr? )` => `respond_with @like`